# User warning: Install zstandard when trying to install with conda

Tags: anaconda, conda, anaconda3

When I try to install with conda (I am using Windows 10) it shows an error saying that it runs without .conda
Prompt output:

`zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.`

And I have not found in forums a good answer to this case. Would appreciate any help.

I have attempted to install a library and it stays processing. I ran the command conda install -c conda-forge zstandard and though I had the same warning, it installed, but the library I am trying to install never ends installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda not working after reinstall - zstandard issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76266770/conda-not-working-after-reinstall-zstandard-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your zstandard version (`conda list | grep zstandard`).
zstandard 0.19 has a bug which prevents conda from updating any packages, including zstandard itself.

To work around this, update zstandard via pip first: `pip install --force-reinstall zstandard zstd`.

For more info see my full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77340146/4126843