# mamba warning: "zstandard could not be imported", although installed

Tags: anaconda, conda, mamba, mambaforge

After a recent update of `Mamba` to 1.5.1 in my `mambaforge` installation, I'm getting the following warning displayed when executing any `mamba` / `conda` command:

```
C:\Users\dummy\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\conda_package_streaming\package_streaming.py:25: UserWarning: zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.
  warnings.warn("zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.")
C:\Users\dummy\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py:29: UserWarning: Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support
  _warnings.warn("Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support")
```

After te message, the command seems to get executed correctly.
I already tried the following steps without any change of this behaviour:

- `mamba install zstandard`
- `mamba uninstall zstandard`, then `mamba install zstandard`
- `mamba install zstandard --force-reinstall`

All of these commands seem to execute properly (right after displaying said warning message), but the warning remains.

Even moe strange, this is the output of

```
mamba list |grep -i zstand
C:\Users\dummy\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\conda_package_streaming\package_streaming.py:25: UserWarning: zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.
  warnings.warn("zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.")
C:\Users\dummy\mambaforge\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py:29: UserWarning: Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support
  _warnings.warn("Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support")
zstandard                 0.19.0          py310h2bbff1b_0
```

So it knows that `zstandard` is installed, but still gives the warning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda not working after reinstall - zstandard issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76266770/conda-not-working-after-reinstall-zstandard-issue)

Answer (score 1):

zstandard 0.19 has a bug which prevents conda from updating any packages, including zstandard itself.

To work around this, update zstandard via pip first: `pip install --force-reinstall zstandard zstd`

For more info see my full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77340146/4126843