# "Package does not exist" error because Conda cannot find recent package versions

Tags: python, conda, mamba

I have an existing Conda 23.1.0 environment managed using Mamba 1.5.1, which was created with the `channels: conda-forge` option.
I want to install the latest version of the `holidays` package, [which is 0.34](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/holidays).

However, `mamba search holidays` gives me

```
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
holidays                       0.9.9            py_0  conda-forge
holidays                      0.9.10            py_0  conda-forge
...
holidays                        0.15    pyhd8ed1ab_0  conda-forge
holidays                        0.16    pyhd8ed1ab_0  conda-forge
holidays                        0.17    pyhd8ed1ab_0  conda-forge
```

If I try `mamba install holidays=0.34` I get

```
Could not solve for environment specs
The following package could not be installed
└─ holidays 0.34**  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel).
```

How do I update the list of available packages so I can install the latest version?

[Edit]
The first time I tried this, this error popped up about zstandard missing. When I installed zstandard, the error disappeared but it didn't solve the problem, hence this question

```
/opt/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda_package_streaming/package_streaming.py:19: UserWarning: zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.
  warnings.warn("zstandard could not be imported. Running without .conda support.")
/opt/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/conda_package_handling/api.py:29: UserWarning: Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support
  _warnings.warn("Install zstandard Python bindings for .conda support")
```

[Edit 2] As it turned out, this was the actual error that was hidden:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zstandard/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .backend_c import *  # type: ignore
ImportError: zstd C API versions mismatch; Python bindings were not compiled/linked against expected zstd version (10505 returned by the lib, 10502 hardcoded in zstd headers, 10502 hardcoded in the cext)
```

Comment: Need more details on the existing environment (e.g., 0.34 requires `pytnon>=3.8`). Does it work to create a new environment?

Comment: @merv No I can't create a new environment either. I have added the yml file I used to the question

Comment: Thanks for adding the info. I cannot recreate this problem. The YAML solved fine for all platforms on prefix.dev (see [resulting conda-lock file](https://prefix.dev//envs/mfansler/so-holidays/27i4wk8977x3/conda-lock.yml)). Maybe you're in offline mode (check `conda config --show offline`)? or the cache needs to be cleaned (run `conda clean -i`)? Otherwise, you may need to share output from `conda info` and `conda config --show-sources` for further troubleshooting.

Comment: @merv Thanks, indeed it must be something specific to this user then. I have added the info and have run a `conda clean -i` but the problem remained.

Comment: Please either 1) add a full example (from command to failure outputs) when creating *a new environment* (`mamba create`); or 2) share the full details of the environment that `mamba install` is being used on. Otherwise, this is not reproducible. Also, any chance that you are sitting behind some cache or proxy? Your config looks fine, but it really seems like you are only getting a very old version of the Conda Forge `repodata.json`. Perhaps you can try manually deleting everything in the `pkgs/cache/` folder?

Comment: For debugging you might also consider throwing in verbosity flag(s), e.g., `-v` or `-vv`. I would probably flush the index (`conda clean -i`) then run a `conda create -n foo -c conda-forge -vv holidays=0.34`, and just observe whence it pulls the `repodata.json`.

Comment: @merv Thanks for the suggestions, I have added the output of the commands you suggested. Interestingly, on one machine the problem had disappeared when I logged in, but on a different machine with the same problem it remains even after clearing caches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider using the .conda file of your desired package :
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/holidays/files
and install it from there ?

Note : I know nothing about Anaconda but i did some research and that's the best i can find to help you, hope it'll help you

Comment: Many thanks for this suggestion, in fact I just noticed that holidays 0.17 (which was the last one shown in the output above) is exactly the last version that was _not_ using the `.conda` format, so I think there must be something wrong with my zstandard installation! I'm trying to fix that now...

Comment: I managed to fix it, many thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I posted another answer here to explain: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77340146/4126843
In short, I first needed to update zstandard with _pip_ instead of conda, then wait a bit, then it started working

Comment: @PHPirate interesting that the problem turned out to be with the **base** environment. I'd suggest more appropriate would be: 1) ensure that no user-level site is leaking `zstandard` or other Python packages into your environments (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/70958434/570918) and 2) ensure that all your **base** packages are from Conda Forge (`mamba update -n base -c conda-forge --all`) - though this latter I suspect would already be true if you installed a Mambaforge **base**.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter so much for this package, but just FYI that installing Conda packages from tarballs (`tar.gz` or `.conda`) will not install their dependencies.

Comment: @merv Yes the problem was in the base environment, the package versions listed there confirmed the problem. I still don't know how I managed to end up with incompatible zstandard and zstd versions since they were both installed from conda-forge. I'm not the only one though: https://github.com/conda-forge/zstandard-feedstock/issues/52